# Evaluate this integral using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid bounded above by the paraboloid of revolution

$z^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$

And below by the $xy$ plane, and on the sides by the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=2ax$

We take $a>0$.

I'm struggling to understand what this would look like graphically, I understand how to find limits of integration for $x$ and $y$ but struggling to find them for $z$. So far i have equated the two terms, but i have got no where with that.

Thanks

Comment: sorry forgot the x

Comment: I have edited it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. the region is symmetric with respect to $xz$ plane.
2. The range for $\theta$ is from $0$ to $\pi/2$.
3. The range for $r$ is from $0$ to $r=2a\cos(\theta)$.
4. The range for $z$ is from ... to ...

See this plotting to undrestand the region better:

[image]

Comment: Thats the part i am failing to understand at the moment

Comment: Nice, how did you make the animation?

Comment: I did it by Maple 18

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

In cylindrical coordinates, the limits are
$$z^2=r^2,\\z=0,\\r^2=2ar\cos\theta\equiv r=2a\cos\theta.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have right now, so correct me if I'm wrong:

I think you meant $z=x^2+y^2$ if you are trying to indicate a paraboloid of revolution. The graph of $z^2=x^2+y^2$ would be two cones.

The cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2ax$ can be represented as follows:

$\begin{align} x^2 + y^2 &= 2ax \\ 
x^2 - 2ax + y^2 &= 0 \\
\left(x^2 - 2ax + a^2\right) + y^2 &= a^2 \\
\left(x - a\right)^2 + y^2 &= a^2 \end{align}$

Since integrating over this circular region would be very complicated, let's translate both objects to the left by $a$ units and move the centre of the circle to the origin. The cylinder would become $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ and your paraboloid of revolution would be $z = \left(x + a\right)^2 + y^2$.

Now we evaluate the integral:

$\begin{align} \iint\limits_{R}{f\left(x, y\right)\,dA} &= \iint\limits_{R}{r\,f\left(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta\right)\,dr\,d\theta} \\ 
&= \int^{2\pi}_{0}{\int^{a}_{0}{r^3 - 2ar^2\cos\theta + a^2r\,dr\,d\theta}} \\ 
\, &= \int^{2\pi}_{0}{a^{4}\left(\frac{3}{4} - \frac{2\cos{\theta}}{3}\right)d\theta} \\ 
&= a^{4}\int^{2\pi}_{0}{\frac{9 - 8\cos{\theta}}{12}\,d\theta} \\
&= \boxed{\boxed{\frac{3\pi a^4}{2}.}} \end{align}$